# in ReactiveX, how do I pass other parameters to Observer.create?

Tags: python, reactivex, rx-py

Using RxPY for illustration purposes.

I want to create an observable from a function, but that function must take parameters. This particular example must return, at random intervals, one of many pre-defined tickers which I want to send to it. My solution thus far is to use a closure:

```
from __future__ import print_function

from rx import Observable
import random
import string
import time

def make_tickers(n = 300, s = 123):
    """ generates up to n unique 3-letter strings geach makde up of uppsercase letters"""
    random.seed(s)
    tickers = [''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for _ in range(3)) for y in range(n)]
    tickers = list(set(tickers)) # unique
    print(len(tickers))
    return(tickers)

def spawn_prices_fn(tickers):
    """ returns a function that will return a random element 
    out of tickers every 20-100 ms, and takes an observable parameter """

    def spawner(observer):
        while True:
            next_tick = random.choice(tickers)
            observer.on_next(next_tick)
            time.sleep(random.randint(20, 100)/1000.0)

    return(spawner)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    spawned = spawn_prices_fn(make_tickers())
    xx = Observable.create(spawned)
    xx.subscribe(lambda s: print(s))
```

Is there a simpler way? Can further parameters be sent to Observable.create's first paramater function, that don't require a closure? What is the canonical advice?

Comment: What kind of pattern are you expecting? Any pseudo code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done in numerous ways, here's one of the solutions that doesn't change your code too much.
Note that tickers generation could also be broken up into a function generating a single string combined with some `rx` magic to be more `rx`-like

I also slightly adjusted the code to make `flake8` happy

```
from __future__ import print_function

import random
import string
import time

from rx import Observable


def make_tickers(n=300, s=123):
    """
    Generates up to n unique 3-letter strings each made up of uppercase letters
    """
    random.seed(s)
    tickers = [''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for _ in range(3))
               for y in range(n)]
    tickers = list(set(tickers))  # unique
    print(len(tickers))
    return(tickers)


def random_picker(tickers):
    ticker = random.choice(tickers)
    time.sleep(random.randint(20, 100) / 1000.0)
    return ticker


if __name__ == "__main__":
    xx = Observable\
        .repeat(make_tickers())\
        .map(random_picker)\
        .subscribe(lambda s: print(s))
```

or a solution without `make_tickers`:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import random
import string
import time

from rx import Observable


def random_picker(tickers):
    ticker = random.choice(tickers)
    time.sleep(random.randint(20, 100) / 1000.0)
    return ticker


if __name__ == "__main__":
    random.seed(123)
    Observable.range(1, 300)\
        .map(lambda _: ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase)
                               for _ in range(3)))\
        .reduce(lambda x, y: x + [y], [])\
        .do_while(lambda _: True)\
        .map(random_picker)\
        .subscribe(lambda s: print(s))
```

`time.sleep` could be moved away from `random_picker` but the code would become a bit trickier

Answer (score 0):

You can also use "partials", to wrap your Subscription method. It allows you to define other arguments, but call rx.create on a method that waits only for Observer and Scheduler:

```
def my_subscription_with_arguments(observer, scheduler, arg1):
    observer.on_next(arg1)

my_subscription_wrapper = functools.partial(my_subscription_with_arguments, arg1='hello')
source = rx.create(my_subscription_wrapper)
```